# How to debug this simple terminal Hangman Python 3 script?

Tags: python

These lines of code express the Hangman game but when I run it I have a problem. I tried to change parts of this but the result doesn't change.

I think the problem is in the guessing function with the for-loops, because when I don't guess the letter, I activate the elif instruction (letter elif! = X), but the exit is wrong and I don't understand the cause.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from random import *

words = [ 'riccardo', 'aereodinamic', 'train', 'love', 'ferrari']
guessing_letter = []

base = [' +--+ ',   ' |  |   ', '    |   ', '    |   ', '    |   ', ' ======']
man =  [' O  |   ', '/|  |', '/|\ |', '/   |', '/ \ |']

life = list(range(0, len(man)))

words = words[randint(0, len(words) -1)]
word = [words[int(i)] for i in range(0, len(words))]

for i in range(0, len(word)):
    guessing_letter.append('_')


def guessing():

    X = input("Guessing Word: ")

    for i in life:
      for letter in word:

        if letter == X:
            for i in range(-1, 3):

                position = word.index(letter)
                guessing_letter[position] = letter

                word[position] = '*'

                if letter not in word:
                    break

            printer()
            print(' ')
            print(guessing_letter)


            guessing_word = ''.join(str(i) for i in guessing_letter)
            if guessing_word == words:
                print('============================')
                print(' ')
                print('You win the match!')

                break



        elif letter != X:

            base[i + 2] = man[i]

            if i == 2 and base[3] == man[1]:
              base[3] = man[2]
              life.remove(i)

            elif i == 4 and base[4] == man[3]:
              base[4] = man[4]
              life.remove(i)

            printer()
            print(guessing_letter)


            if  base == [base[0], base[1], man[0], man[2], man[4], base[5]]:
                break

        X = input('Guesing WOrd: ')



def printer():
    for i in range(0,len(base)):
        print(base[i])


guessing()
```

Output:

```
 Guessing Word: s
 +--+ 
 |  |   
 O  |   
    |   
    |   
 ======
['_', '_', '_', '_']
Guessing Word: l
 +--+ 
 |  |   
 O  |   
    |   
    |   
 ======
 
['l', '_', '_', '_']
Guessing Word: o
 +--+ 
 |  |   
 O  |   
/|  |
    |   
 ======
['l', '_', '_', '_']
Guessing Word: v
 +--+ 
 |  |   
 O  |   
/|\ |
/|\ |
 ======
['l', '_', '_', '_']
Guessing Word: e
 +--+ 
 |  |   
 O  |   
/|\ |
/|\ |
/   |
['l', '_', '_', '_']
Guessing Word: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Hangman.py", line 79, in <module>
    guessing()
  File "./Hangman.py", line 68, in guessing
    guessing()
  File "./Hangman.py", line 49, in guessing
    guessing()
  File "./Hangman.py", line 68, in guessing
    guessing()
  File "./Hangman.py", line 68, in guessing
    guessing()
  File "./Hangman.py", line 68, in guessing
    guessing()
  File "./Hangman.py", line 53, in guessing
    base[i + 2] = man[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: In your elif, you are doing `letter!=word`, which will never happen because the loop is `for letter in word`. you probably mean to use `elif letter not in word:`. You are using recursion in your code, but there is no way to stop it. There should be return statements to break it in both if and else, in case when you either win or loose (you don't even need recursion probably). Your particular error is because base does not have an index i+2

Comment: @SajanGohil i tried to remove the recursion and change elif letter != word:  in elif letter != X:.  but the output is equal

Comment: can you update the code in the question, also, it should be letter!=X, my suggestion was incorrect

Comment: @SajanGohil I have update the code.

Comment: There is still no exit condition for the function. What happens if you guess the word? It will continue till the lives are left. And since you call tge function itself, the life counter resets. You are basically just starting the game again, but the guessing letters are not reset. There is also no break statement in elif. You are not checking all the letters in the word, you just call the function again. Also, removing elements from the list you are iterating over will cause problems, look more into that

Comment: @SajanGohil i have update the code: i have remove the recursion and i have added a break statement but i still have problem

Comment: There os still a lot of debugging to do, like I previously said, you are updating life while you iterate over it. I suggest you use a debugger or print statements and check what part of code is not working like you expected. The error is that you are doing base[i+2], if i is len(base), you won't even have base[i] because index starts from 0